# I am trying to read a .epub format but i am getting an encoded stuff in my web view

Tags: android, webview, epub, epublib

This is the code i am using

```
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.List;

import nl.siegmann.epublib.domain.Book;
import nl.siegmann.epublib.domain.TOCReference;
import nl.siegmann.epublib.epub.EpubReader;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

WebView webview;
String line, line1 = "", finalstr = "";
int i = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webview = findViewById(R.id.web_view);

    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();


    String javascrips = "";
    try {
        InputStream input = this.getAssets().open(
                "adventures.epub");

        int size;
        size = input.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size/10000];
        input.read(buffer);
        input.close();

        javascrips = new String(buffer);


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", javascrips,
            "application/epub+zip", "UTF-8", null);

}
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private void logTableOfContents(List<TOCReference> tocReferences, int depth) {
    if (tocReferences == null) {
        return;
    }

    for (TOCReference tocReference : tocReferences) {
        StringBuilder tocString = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
            tocString.append("\t");
        }
        tocString.append(tocReference.getTitle());
        Log.i("TOC", tocString.toString());

        try {
            InputStream is = tocReference.getResource().getInputStream();
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {

                Log.v("line" + i, Html.fromHtml(line).toString());

                line1 = line1.concat(Html.fromHtml(line).toString());
            }
            finalstr = finalstr.concat("\n").concat(line1);
            i++;
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }

        logTableOfContents(tocReference.getChildren(), depth + 1);
    }
    webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", finalstr, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
}
}
```

i am getting the out put in my web view as

onCreate: PK
                                                               ����������s��Goa�,������������������mimetypeapplication/epub+zipPK������s��GKU�����������������META-INF/container.xml]��
                                                               �0����*5z��X�>@L�LwC�����"g�of���zq�.:&������Y��) ��xTZ�da��

I recieve this out put on my moto e and a blank web view in my nexus

Comment: What makes you believe a webview could render epubs?

Comment: then what is the right method i should do @laalto

Comment: Use an epub library.

Comment: everything is a paid one.. I also need the page turning effect. most of the libraries support only scrolling, and also i need to get a library supported for android studio @laalto

Answer (score 0):

This should be a coding format conversion error, you do not have to try transcoding. Or get the text encoding format, use this text encoding format conversion utf-8

Comment: what should i do i found that my  lines  byte[] buffer = new byte[size/10000];
        input.read(buffer); itself is reuturning this